# Trying to integrate paramiko and pyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python

I am new at programming using python. I am trying to create a python script that connects to different Linux servers to extract data or check if some services are running. I am able to send a command -> use paramiko to extract data -> send the data to telegram. The problem is that i am trying to make the code shorter creating a file only for functions and call it but i can not get this to work. Here is the file(no executable) and the code:

File:

```
def tx(message):

    host = "111.222.333.444"

    user = "user"

    password = "12345"

    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

    ssh.connect(hostname=host, username=user, password=password)

    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("sudo tail -1 /usr/local/bin/noc/respaldos/diatx.txt")

    time.sleep(.5)

    output = stdout.readlines()

    ssh.close()

    return output
```

Script:

```
    import telebot  
    import paramiko
    import time
    import commands


    TOKEN = "abcde"

    bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

    @bot.message_handler(commands=['tx'])

    commands.tx(message)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, output)

    bot.polling()
```

My intention is to create 20 functions for different data and checks but all in functions inside the commands.py file. I have tried with `from commands import *` but that did not work either

Comment: What is your project structure?
What does not work? Importing?

Comment: You could consider using `fabric2` instead of `paramiko`. And use the `Connection.run` method to execute ssh commands. (Just a suggestion, it uses paramiko under the hood)

Comment: @Alexper Thank you for your suggestion, I will definitely look into it. May be is because I am new but I am getting this error message when running the script ```File "./prueba.py", line 56
    commands.tx(message)
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax```

Comment: I have tried putting the import of paramiko inside the function and get the same error. I have 1 server where the script fro the bot will run as a service and 10 other servers where I want to check services status, restart services like glassfish, pm2,etc. 
I have a bash script already doing it, but i want to recode it using Python for speed and readability purposes.

Comment: See my answer, this is due to how decorators work. You're trying to decorate a calling function. You can only decorate function definitions.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few problems in your code.
First, I don't see `message` being defined anywhere.
Second, the way you use the `bot.message_handler` decorator.

The decorator function returns a function object that will replace the function you decorate. See the code:

```py
@bot.message_handler(commands=['tx'])
def tx(message):
   command.tx(message)
```

However, I don't know telebot library. I'm not sure how this is supposed to work.